# mongoose populate to array of ObjectIds

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

This is my schema

```
friends: {
    type: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }],
    required:false,
    validate: [arrayLimit, '{PATH} exceeds the limit of 3']
  }
```

I want to find all the user related Like populate but with multi user
and I do not want all the user fields just the relvant
for example

```
const responses = await Response.find({}).populate("friends", {name:1, username:1})
```

Comment: Your populate looks perfectly valid with that projection object. What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

According to [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) yo can do something like:

```js
const responses = await Response
  .find({})
  .populate({
    path: 'friends',
    select: 'name username -_id'
  })
```